# python OOP getting None

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I'm testing out my understanding of OOP and I've run into a problem where after printing the code below I get "None". I have checked other code and mirrored some of the logic as well as ran debug and saw that the items I'm try to put into the cart appear, but why do I get None?

The len method defined is working fine I see that as I continue adding products to the cart the count increases.

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self, name, price, quantity):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity


class Client:
    def __init__(self, name, balance):
        self.name = name
        self.balace = balance


class Cart:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
        self.quantity = 0

    def add_item(self, product):
        self.items.append(product)
        

    def view_cart(self):
        return len(self.items)


client1 = Client('Sven', 100)
product1 = Product('Tomato', 10, 1)
product2 = Product('Milk', 10, 1)
product3 = Product('Beer', 10, 1)
cart = Cart()

print(cart.add_item(product1))
print(cart.add_item(product2))
print(cart.add_item(product3))
print(cart.view_cart())
```

Comment: The method `append` adds an element in place (i.e. changes the list it is applied to) and returns `None` (so does `add_item`). Try calling `cart.add_item(product1)` then `print(cart.items)`

Comment: It returns only the objects. I've figured it out. Forgot to add the def __repr__ so it can display them as a string.